# Printing values using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I need to print certain fixed values as well as values from other files, `file1` and `file2` into new file output using `awk` command.

#### file1:

```
100,1
102,3
104,4
```

#### file2:

```
103,4
108,6
109,7
```

#### my command

I did with the help of paste command:
In file1:first 4 fields are present
In file3:contents between file1 and file2
Merged all files using paste command. I wanted to do it directly without paste command usage
    awk -F '{print "100",0,1,contents_of_file1,"1","0",contents_of_file2}' > output

#### output:

```
100,0,1,100,1,1,0,103,4
100,0,1,102,3,1,0,108,6
100,0,1,104,4,1,0,109,7
```

First 3 values are default fixed, 4th and 5th column values are from file1,6th and 7th column values are fixed default values and last 2 columns are contents of file2

Comment: _I need to do X_ is not a good question. You should explain what you want to do, what you've tried and where you're stuck. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: See the edit to  see what I have tried

Comment: It's better but it's not clear where all the fields in your output come from. You should edit to show us.

Comment: edited output section above

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do the whole thing in one invocation of awk, by saving the contents of the first file to a buffer:

```
awk -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}{print "100,0,1",a[FNR],"1,0",$0}' file1 file2
```

The `NR==FNR` condition on the first block means that it is only run for the first file, where the total record number is equal to the record number for the current file. Each line from the first file is saved to the array `a`, using the record number as the index. `next` skips any further statements.

For the second file, the first block is skipped as `NR` is no longer equal to `FNR`. The value from the array corresponding to the same record in the first file is used, along with the fixed values and the contents of the current record, `$0`. Each field in the output is separated by `OFS`, which has been set to a comma.

Alternatively, you could use paste to feed in the content of both files at the same time:

```
paste -d, file1 file2 | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print "100,0,1",$1,$2,"1,0",$3,$4}'
```

Comment: Can you explain the first answer?